# Error in docs about neo4j cluster joining?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to understand how neo4j cluster creation/joining works as it is not behaving properly in our application.

So I'm starting from scratch and creating a 3 box cluster as per the tutorial: http://neo4j.com/docs/2.3.4/ha-setup-tutorial.html

The following note is copy/pasted from the tutorial:

> Startup Time When running in HA mode, the startup script returns
>   immediately instead of waiting for the server to become available.
>   This is because the instance does not accept any requests until a
>   cluster has been formed. In the example above this happens when you
>   start the second instance. To keep track of the startup state you can
>   follow the messages in console.log — the path is printed before the
>   startup script returns.

However when I startup the second instance, my cluster is still not formed... I need to startup the 3rd one for the cluster to start.

Is this an error in the neo4j docs?

Furthermore, is there a way to "force" an instance to become a master on cluster startup? For example, if I have 3 nodes and 2 of them fail and need to be re-installed, when I restart the cluster, how can I force the one with the valid database to become master? Isn't there a chance the 2nd or 3rd one with a blank database would become master?

Answer (score 2):

When you start a cluster for the first time, or stop all instances and then start them again, the initial cluster MUST consist of all members listed in ha.initial_hosts. In addition, all instances in the cluster should have the exact same entries in ha.initial_hosts for the cluster to come up quickly and cleanly. The cluster will not form until all of the instances are up and running.

Comment: Thanks - so would it be safe to say that the only way to build a cluster from scratch AND to ensure that a specific DB is used would be to 1) start the first host with initial_hosts of only itself, which will come up, then 2) start  the other 2 empty nodes with the full list of initial_hosts populated?